# How to use MOCK_METHOD on a virtual function from a different class inside a Mock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to use `EXPECT_CALL` to set the return value of the function that resides in a different class than what the mock class inherits from.

In the following snippet, I was wondering if there's a way to use `EXPECT_CALL` on `someFunction()` that's a public function of `Bar` inside a unit test through `bar` object of `UnitTest` class but it seems to error out.

One thing I know is I would need to use `MOCK_METHOD` for `someFunction` to override it to expect `EXPECT_CALL` but not sure how could I do inside the Mock class?

```
// Bar.hpp
class Bar
{
    public:
    virtual bool someFunction();
};

// Foo.hpp
namespace sw::foo_state
{
    class Foo
    {
        Bar _bar;
        
        public:
        Foo(Bar&& bar) : _bar(std::move(bar)) {}
        
        void TestFunction()
        {
          _bar.someFunction();
        }
    };
};

// MockClass.hpp
namespace sw
{
    class Mock : public foo_state::Foo
    {
        Mock(Bar&& bar) : Foo(std::move(bar)) {}
    };
};

// UnitTest.cpp
using namespace sw::foo_state;
class UnitTest
{
    public:
    Bar bar;
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Mock>(std::move(bar));   
};


TEST_F(UnitTest, Test)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(bar, someFunction()).WillOnce(Return(true)); //  error: ‘class sw::foo_state::Bar’ has no member named ‘gmock_someFunction’; did you mean ‘someFunction’?

   ptr->TestFunction();
}
```

Comment: That can't be done. You can only `EXPECT_CALL`s on `MOCK_METHOD`s. But there seems to be a deeper architectural problem in your code that you should solve instead of trying to mock strangely.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You only need to change your `class Foo` constructor to accept a pointer or a reference to take advantage of `class Bar` polymorphism:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    virtual bool someFunction()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar& bar): _bar{ bar} {}
    void TestFunction()
    {
        std::cout << _bar.someFunction() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    Bar& _bar;  // can also be std::unique_ptr<Bar> if you prefer to own the object
};

struct MockBar : public Bar
{
    MOCK_METHOD0(someFunction, bool());
};

using testing::Return;

TEST(xxx, yyy)
{
    MockBar mBar;
    // ON_CALL(mBar, someFunction()).WillByDefault(Return(false));  // if you don't want to force expectation
    EXPECT_CALL(mBar, someFunction()).WillOnce(Return(false));
    Foo foo(mBar);
    foo.TestFunction();
}
```

Comment: in your second example at least, `Mock` class doesn't exist that inherits from `Foo`? cause that was the initial design

Comment: Sorry I edited the snippet a bit; didn't realize it would be essential to put in after seeing your solution: `bar::someFunction` is accessed through `Foo`'s public method (`TestFunction)` so I can't directly do `mFoo.getBar()->someFunction`

Comment: Oki got it @xyf . What you need was more or less 2nd part of my answer - dependency injection. Edited the answer to contain only relevant info.